# How to Update a Data in Room Database?

Tags: android, database, android-room

I'm trying to update the Data of a Table in a room database but the item isn't updating.The Code is as
Entity:

```
 @Entity(tableName = "modes")
public class Mode extends BaseObservable implements Serializable {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int id;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "Mode_Name")
    private String ModeName;
      @ColumnInfo(name = "Mode_Brightness_ProgressBar")
    private Integer ModeBrightnessProgressBar;
```

Dao:

```
    @Query("UPDATE modes SET Mode_Brightness_ProgressBar = :brightnessProgress  WHERE id = :id")
    fun updateBrightness(id: Int, brightnessProgress: Int) { 
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
 fun updateBrightness(id: Int, brightness: Int) {
    mRepository.updateBrightness(id, brightness)
}
```

Repositary:

```
 fun updateBrightness(id: Int, brightness: Int) {
    UpdateCheckInAsyncTask(modeDao, id, brightness).execute()
}


  private class UpdateCheckInAsyncTask internal constructor(
        private val dao: DaoAccess,
        Id: Int,
        Brightness: Int
    ) :
        AsyncTask<Void?, Void?, Void?>() {

        private val mId: Int = Id
        private val mbrightness: Int = Brightness

        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): Void? {
            val entity: Mode = dao.getMode(mId)
            dao.updateBrightness(mId, mbrightness)
            return null
        }
    }
```

Fragment:

```
 GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                activityViewModel.updateBrightness(id, currentBrightnessForMode)
    }.invokeOnCompletion {
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main)
        {
            Log.d("DB_CLIENT", "Data updated")
        }
    }
```

Any help Will be much Appreciated.
Thankyou

Comment: Are you sure to use correct id?

Comment: yess i debugged the code and it is accessing the correct id from fragment to Dao @ysfcyln

Comment: the `updateBrightness` function in the dao should not have body. remove additional `{}` of the function and check it again.

Comment: Its working Now! Thankyou for your help. @HamidSj